# AlertDialog Builder setSingleChoiceItems from enum

Tags: android, listview, enums, android-alertdialog

I have a simple AlertDialog with a setSingleChoiceItems list of two elements which works fine.

```
final CharSequence[] blackwhite = {"White", "Black"};

AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);


    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Title");
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setSingleChoiceItems(blackwhite, -1,null)
            .setPositiveButton("Start", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    ListView lw = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView();
                    Object checkedItem = lw.getAdapter().getItem(lw.getCheckedItemPosition());

                     // Do something with checkedItem
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
```

In the rest of the code, these two items actually correspond to an enum:

```
public enum Player {
    WHITE, BLACK
}
```

Is there an elegant way of using the enum directly in setSingleChoiceItems without manually converting to String/CharSequence? For instance if I later decide to change "WHITE" to "GREEN" in the enum only, this should automatically show up in the alert dialog as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can obtain the String value of a `Player` using the `toString()` method.

```
Player.WHITE.toString(); // returns "WHITE"
```

You could do something like:

```
public enum Player {

  WHITE, BLACK, GREEN, PURPLE

  public static String[] getValues() {
    String[] strs = new String[Player.values().length];
    int i = 0;

    for (Player p: all)
      strs[i++] = p.toString().toLowerCase();

    return strs; // ["white", "black", "green", "purple"]
  }
}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Helps somewhat, thanks. (I had to replace "Collection<Player>" with "Player[]" and "size" with "length").  This gives me a string array which I can feed into the dialog.

Comment: Still I am not fully happy because when a singleChoiceItem has been selected, I will basically get a String which I have to compare to an element of the enum converted via toString(). What I don't like is that I compare strings and not the underlying enum elements. Basically what I would like to have is that I feed Player.values()  into setSingleChoiceItems which uses toString() for display, but in the onClick method, "Object checkedItem = lw.getAdapter().getItem(lw.getCheckedItemPosition());" is of type Player, not String. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, now I correct... you can use the method ``Player.valueOf()`` to convert a string in the enum represented by the string. For example ``Player.valueOf("WHITE")`` should returns Player.WHITE (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String)).